# A Simple Form with Validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, validation, if-statement

I would like to modify a JavaScript Code and add an extra field such as:

- The first text box for the user to enter his/her address,
- The second text box for the user to enter a telephone number.

The Code looks like so:

```js
var myForm = document.form1;

function btnCheckFormClick(e) {
  var txtName = myForm.txtName;
  var txtAge = myForm.txtAge;
  if (txtAge.value == "" || txtName.value == "") {
    alert("Please complete all of the form");
    if (txtName.value == "") {
      txtName.focus();
    } else {
      txtAge.focus();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Thanks for completing the form " + txtName.value);
  }
}

function txtAgeBlur(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (isNaN(target.value)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid age");
    target.focus();
    target.select();
  }
}

function txtNameChange(e) {
  alert("Hi " + e.target.value);
}
myForm.txtName.addEventListener("change", txtNameChange);
myForm.txtAge.addEventListener("blur", txtAgeBlur);
myForm.btnCheckForm.addEventListener("click", btnCheckFormClick);
```

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
  Please enter the following details:
  <p>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="txtName" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Age:
    <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Check details" name="btnCheckForm">
  </p>
</form>
```

Here is what I tried already BUt it's not working(Not Validation):

```js
var myForm = document.form1;

function btnCheckFormClick(e) {
  var txtName = myForm.txtName;
  var txtAge = myForm.txtAge;
  var txtAddress = myForm.txtAddress;
  var txtTelNumber = myForm.txtTelNumber;
  if (txtAge.value == "" || txtName.value == "" && txtAddress.value == "" || txtTelNumber.value == "") {
    alert("Please complete all of the form");
    if (txtName.value == "" && txtAddress.value == "" && txtTelNumber.value == "") {
      txtName.focus();
    } else {
      txtAge.focus();
    } else {
      txtAddress.focus();
    } else {
      txtTelNumber.focus();
    } else {
      alert("Thanks for completing the form " + txtName.value);
    }
  }
}

function txtAgeBlur(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (isNaN(target.value)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid age");
    target.focus();
    target.select();
  }
}

function txtTelNumberBlur(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (isNaN(target.value)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
    target.focus();
    target.select();
  }
}

function txtAddressChange(e) {
  alert("Your address is: " + e.target.value);
}

function txtNameChange(e) {
  alert("Hi " + e.target.value);
}
myForm.txtName.addEventListener("change", txtNameChange);
myForm.txtAge.addEventListener(, txtAgeBlur);
myForm.txtAddress.addEventListener("change", txtAddressChange);
myForm.txtTelNumber.addEventListener("change", txtTelNumberBlur);
myForm.btnCheckForm.addEventListener("click", btnCheckFormClick);
```

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
  Please enter the following details:
  <p>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="txtName" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Age:
    <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3" />
  </p>
  Address:
  <input type="text" name="txtAddress" size="40" maxlength="25" />
  </p>
  Telephone Number:
  <input type="text" name="txtTelNumber" size="20" maxlength="10" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Check details" name="btnCheckForm">
  </p>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and point me out to where look at?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have more than one `else` clause for an `if`.

Comment: I know that won't solve your problem now but there are really great working packages for creating forms and validation out there which save you a lot of work and besides teach you some "good practices" of code design.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the MDN documentation for [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). You might also want to look at the documentation for the [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to get a better understanding of how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple `else` blocks for the same `if`. You should be checking each field in a separate `else if` block.

And in the outer `if`, all the checks must be connected with `||`. You had a mix of `&&` and `||`.

```js
var myForm = document.form1;

function btnCheckFormClick(e) {
  var txtName = myForm.txtName;
  var txtAge = myForm.txtAge;
  var txtAddress = myForm.txtAddress;
  var txtTelNumber = myForm.txtTelNumber;
  if (txtAge.value == "" || txtName.value == "" || txtAddress.value == "" || txtTelNumber.value == "") {
    alert("Please complete all of the form");
    if (txtName.value == "") {
      txtName.focus();
    } else if (txtAge.value == "") {
      txtAge.focus();
    } else if (txtAddress.value == "") {
      txtAddress.focus();
    } else if (txtTelNumber.value == "") {
      txtTelNumber.focus();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Thanks for completing the form " + txtName.value);
  }
}

function txtAgeBlur(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (isNaN(target.value)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid age");
    target.focus();
    target.select();
  }
}

function txtTelNumberBlur(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (isNaN(target.value)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
    target.focus();
    target.select();
  }
}

function txtAddressChange(e) {
  alert("Your address is: " + e.target.value);
}

function txtNameChange(e) {
  alert("Hi " + e.target.value);
}
myForm.txtName.addEventListener("change", txtNameChange);
myForm.txtAge.addEventListener("blur", txtAgeBlur);
myForm.txtAddress.addEventListener("change", txtAddressChange);
myForm.txtTelNumber.addEventListener("change", txtTelNumberBlur);
myForm.btnCheckForm.addEventListener("click", btnCheckFormClick);
```

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
  Please enter the following details:
  <p>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="txtName" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Age:
    <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3" />
  </p>
  Address:
  <input type="text" name="txtAddress" size="40" maxlength="25" />
  </p>
  Telephone Number:
  <input type="text" name="txtTelNumber" size="20" maxlength="10" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Check details" name="btnCheckForm">
  </p>
</form>
```